# Deploying Java Web Application on WebsitePanel platform

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, web-hosting

I have created a web application using primefaces, spring, hibernate, mySQL (as database) and  I used Tomcat7 as development server.

Now my client wants to deploy the app on a server which has "[WebsitePanel](http://www.websitepanel.net/)" installed.

Is this even possible ?
Could someone give me a link to a tutorial on how to do that ?
Should I install a specific "extension" on this platform before starting deploying  java webApps ?

P.S. Because I see that WebsitePanel is not even defined as tag here I will post a link to they website http://www.websitepanel.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     The powerful, flexible open source WebsitePanel platform gives users simple point-and-
click control over Windows Server applications including IIS, SQL Server, Exchange 2010, Sharepoint 2010, OCS, Lync and Hyper-V Deployments.
```

Please explain your client, that it has nothing to do with your app! The panel is for Windows Server Applications and I don't see you're using any. But if you'd still like, here's what can be easily done.

Get a windows server and install websitepanel. Configure java using http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org/ or http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/iishowto.html

may be you can have something like mydomain.com having website-panel or another domain or subdomain like app.mydomain.com for java.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer on that is YES!

The problem whose with their hosting service technical support  and also a lack from my knowledge. Because I did not know what is  IIS  or WebsitePanel
So what are those:

**IIS** more or less is the same as Tomcat, Jboss, Jetty etc ( but
   specific for web application developed in .Net)

**WebsitePanel** more or less is the same as [Cpanel](http://cpanel.net/) a platform for managing server used for web application. 
What could you do from this platform:
   -  manage one or more instance of IIS, Tomcat etc
   -  configure FTP account ( install, add account  and configure rights for them )
   -  manage a lot other functionality regarding a server as port access, DNS configuration, permission on that machine  etc etc.